# Problem with PDF Viewer in communities (Chrome)

Tags: visualforce, lightning, pdf, customer-community

We have a custom button to generate a PDF from a visual force page. Works well internally in classic but the viewer is cutoff in communities in Chrome ( see below). You can still scroll up and down in the small space to view the entire pdf, but the view space is blocked by the black box. I've tried every "window output setting" in the custom button with no luck. Something in lightning/communit/js is overriding the PDF output viewer. If you expand the window, it will eventually resize to the normal viewer. Strange!

[image: Black Box cutting off PDF view]

Comment: It seems the issue is caused by some Chrome plugin. Are you using any?

Comment: I am, but none of them are enabled in the private incognito browser mode that this is occurring in. (Same issue happens in regular Chrome browser window). It does work perfectly in Safari (Firefox throws a flash plugin error).